# bind radiogroup with different data in every row based on datatable

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

i added gridcontrol with two columns , Column 1 represent string and bind from datatable and another column represent radiogroupitem but i want to add different radiobutton value in every row based on question like in first row add 
( Fine - Bad ) and next row add ( here - not here ) and last row add ( not yet - yes - tonight )

```
//bind question column
DataTable dtt = new DataTable();

dtt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(string));

dtt.Rows.Add("How are you ?");
dtt.Rows.Add("Where are you ?");
dtt.Rows.Add("are you sleepy ?");

gridControl1.DataSource = dtt;

gridControl1.ForceInitialize();

// Bind radiobuttonitem
DataTable dataSource = new DataTable();
dataSource.Columns.Add("TypeID", typeof(int));
dataSource.Columns.Add("TypeName", typeof(string));

dataSource.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, "A" });
dataSource.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, "B" });
dataSource.Rows.Add(new object[] { 3, "C" });

foreach (DataRow dr in dataSource.Rows)
   repositoryItemRadioGroup1.Items
        .Add(new DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.RadioGroupItem(dr["TypeID"], dr["TypeName"].ToString()));
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8BYCQ.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [CustomRowCellEdit](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView.CustomRowCellEdit.event) event to assign different editors to individual cells. You can store questions and RepositoryItemRadioGroups in a dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, RepositoryItemRadioGroup> repositories = new Dictionary<string, RepositoryItemRadioGroup>();

RepositoryItemRadioGroup group1 = new RepositoryItemRadioGroup();
group1.Items.Add(new DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.RadioGroupItem("Fine", "Fine"));
group1.Items.Add(new DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.RadioGroupItem("Bad", "Bad"));
repositories.Add("How are you?", group1);

RepositoryItemRadioGroup group2 = new RepositoryItemRadioGroup();
group2.Items.Add(new DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.RadioGroupItem("Here", "Here"));
group2.Items.Add(new DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.RadioGroupItem("There", "There"));
repositories.Add("Where are you?", group2);
```

In the CustomRowCellEdit event handler, call the [GetRowCellValue](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView.GetRowCellValue.overloads) method to get the question, obtain the corresponding repository item from the dictionary and set the e.RepositoryItem parameter:

```
void GridView1_CustomRowCellEdit(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.CustomRowCellEditEventArgs e) {
    GridView view = sender as GridView;
    if (e.Column.FieldName == "Answer" && view.IsValidRowHandle(e.RowHandle)) {
        string question = (string)view.GetRowCellValue(e.RowHandle, "Question");
        RepositoryItemRadioGroup item;
        if(repositories.TryGetValue(question, out item))
            e.RepositoryItem = item;
    }
}
```

See also: [Modify and Validate Cell Values](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/753/Controls-and-Libraries/Data-Grid/Data-Editing-and-Validation/Modify-and-Validate-Cell-Values)