# get value of RepositoryItemRadioGroup

Tags: winforms, devexpress

i need to get selected value of RepositoryItemRadioGroup

how can i get it ??

```
      for (int i = 0; i < gridView1.RowCount; i++)
        {
            int rowHandle = gridView1.GetVisibleRowHandle(i);


QuestionsAndAnswers row = (QuestionsAndAnswers)((GridView)gridControl1.MainView).GetRow(rowHandle);
         //  row.RadioGroup> represent RepositoryItemRadioGroup
          //i need to get selected value in row.radiongroup

        }
```

Comment: Use the GridView's GetRowCellValue method. The returned value will equal the EditValue of the selected radio group item.

Comment: i need to save data in database so how can i use this event ?? because my code in button

Comment: It's not an event, it's a method. Just invoke it in your button's Click handler, retrieve the value and pass it to whatever method you use to update your database.

Answer (score 0):

It is not quite clear to me why you need to get access to the RadioGroup directly. If you have bound your GridView to the collection of the QuestionsAndAnswers objects you should not iterate GridView rows itself due to the fact that all the values are already mapped onto the QuestionsAndAnswers properties in a two-way manner. Thus iterate your QuestionsAndAnswers collection directly:

```
List<QuestionsAndAnswers> qaList = new List<QuestionsAndAnswers> { 
    new QuestionsAndAnswers(){ Question ="How are you?" }
}
// data binding
gridControl1.DataSource = qaList;
...
void getAnswersBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    foreach (QuestionsAndAnswers qa in qaList){
        var answer = qa.Answer;
        // do something
    }
}
```

If you are bound the GridView in another manner, please, update your question with the detailed description:
 - how you bind the GridView to data;
 - whether or not you use [the approach demonstrated by @Alex.T](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47920126/1010363) in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47915757/bind-radiogroup-with-different-data-in-every-row-based-on-datatable);
 - whether or no you read and understand the [documentation](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/753/Controls-and-Libraries/Data-Grid/Data-Editing-and-Validation/Modify-and-Validate-Cell-Values);

BTW, the main question is  - have [you contacted the DevExpress team direcly](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Create) and what their guys said?

Answer (score 0):

```
    for (int i = 0; i < gridView1.RowCount; i++)
        {
         // can't get answer of last record so i added test line in the last record to get all answers without new last record
            if (i==gridView1.RowCount-1)
            {
                continue;
            }
            int rowHandle = gridView1.GetVisibleRowHandle(i);
            string ResultAnswer = (string)gridView1.GetRowCellValue(rowHandle, "Answer");
            string ResultQuest = (string)gridView1.GetRowCellValue(rowHandle, "Question");

        }
```